# Setting variables as certain parts of stdin

Tags: shell

I have three variables, `x`, `y`, and `z`, and I want to read in the first, third, and sixth words from stdin (doesn't make much sense but this is just for example), and stdin is

`foo turtle bar dog bird baz qwer asdf`

`x` should be `foo`, `y` should be `bar`, and `z` should be `baz`

How can I take some parts of stdin and read it into variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in string to array, declare X, Y, Z variables with array element pointers.

```
#! /bin/bash --posix

#STRING="foo turtle bar dog bird baz qwer asdf"

read -p "Input String: " STRING

IFS=' ' read -a arr <<< "$STRING"

X=${arr[0]}
Y=${arr[2]}
Z=${arr[5]}

printf "x is $X\ny is $Y\nz is $Z\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the first through sixth, use whichever you want:

```
read -p "Enter values:  " one two three four five six
```